# Redraw Polyline Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I have a polyline with several points, and I want to redraw it many times inside a loop where I am rearranging the points. I have used setLatLngs function, but it seems to redraw the whole polyline once.

How can I redraw a polyline in a loop?

Here is the code:

```
test()
{
    for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        this._polyline.setLatLngs(this.shuffle(this._polylinePoints));
    }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2vqdcoqd/10/) is a jsfiddle.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more of what you are looking for here?

Comment: Yes, of course, snkashis. In the test function the polyline should be redrawed one hundred times, but it is only redrawed once. If you push "Test" button in the jsfiddle, the test function is executed and I expected to see the polyline been redrawed one hundred times, but it is redrawed once. I need to redraw a polyline several times because I am replacing all the points in the polyline several times.

Comment: But it is being redrawn many time, you just cannot see it. Watch what I am talking about  in your `test()` with `   self = this;
  for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
      setTimeout(function() {
         self._polyline.setLatLngs(self.shuffle(self._polylinePoints));
      },1000*i)
  }`

Comment: Yes snkashis, you are right. I need to see the redrawn polyline in each iteration. How can I do it?

Comment: Well, like my example before...why dont you just set up a function that recursively calls itself with `setTimeout` for the duration you are looking for?

Comment: I am not very fluent in English, sorry about that, snkashis. I meant to say how can I do it without using setTimeout and a callback function (I don`t know if it is possible). However your current solution is perfectly valid and I will mark it as useful if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since if you want to see each iteration's configuration for a certain amount of time..you will probably have to use `setTimeout`, like in the below example.Or make something recursive instead.Here I just constantly make the timeout larger, a recursive approach is a lot more efficient.

```
self = this; 
for (var i=0;i<100;i++) { 
   setTimeout(function() {
       self._polyline.setLatLngs(self.shuffle(self._polylinePoin‌​ts));
   },1000*i) 
}
```

Here is recursive example below

```
self = this;
var runs = 0;

shufflePoints = function() {
    if (runs < 100) {
      runs++;
      self._polyline.setLatLngs(self.shuffle(self._polylinePoin‌​ts));
      setTimeout(function() {
       shufflePoints()
      },1000)
    }
}
```